# Errors when running Cron

Tags: cron

I can't run cron; see the [video capture](http://screencast.com/t/DzDXq3kR4t3) I created.

If I click "Run cron" in the admin menu I'm redirected to another URL.

If I go to mysite.com/cron.php, I get the "Access denied" message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I click "Run cron" in the admin menu I'm redirected to another URL.

You have a node using the PHP filter, and calling `drupal_goto()`. That node is then indexed, the PHP code is executed, and you are then redirect. Don't do that ;)

> I can't run cron; see the video capture I created.

You need to specify a cron key when accessing cron.php directly. You can find a link with the key on your Status report page (admin/reports/status).

Comment: thanks. I can't find it... Is there any way to find this node making a search in the database?

Comment: Yes - use this script to search everywhere in your DB for the URL that you are getting redirected to - you can then see the nid of the node in question. http://code.google.com/p/anywhereindb/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot invoke cron.php directly in Drupal 7 :)
Did you try running admin/config/system/cron by going to configuration > system > cron ?

Comment: You are right but if to go to admin/config/system/cron and click 'Run cron' I get redirected to this url: admin/commerce/orders/154

Comment: You can invoke cron.php, even in Drupal 7.

Comment: I thought you can't visit cron.php to invoke cron manually in drupal 7 (http://drupal.org/node/158922)

Comment: The page you linked says: "In that same section, core also provides a link with a unique cron_key **to run cron from outside your site**."