# Cron is not working - leading to user/0/edit instead

Tags: cron

When I was trying to migrate my site and export the database I realised that the cache_form field is enormous. According to suggestions I have found online the proper way to solve this is to run cron. So I try to run cron by going to the admin/config/system/cron page, and in there it said that cron was last run 3 weeks ago.

When I press run cron or when I visit the link with the cron key provided in that admin/config/system/cron page, they have both led me to user/0/edit instead of running cron. I did a quick search among the files I have made changes to in the site directory in these three weeks and none of them are leading to user/uid/edit. I wonder what else can I do to solve this properly?

Thanks!

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/node/553430#comment-5762858

Comment: thanks @arpitr , but i have checked all the page/files i have made changes in and none of them are leading to ('user/'.$GLOBALS['user']->uid.'/edit'), so I am not sure what else can i do

Comment: do you have custom cron jobs running? You check the codes for custom implementation of hook_cron

Comment: @arpitr I just checked and no custom cron jobs are running other than some regular ones included in modules like backup and migrate or capatcha

Comment: Check this exactly the problem you are facing: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/25025/errors-when-running-cron

Answer (score 1):

I think your not logged in, that's why going to  " user/0/edit " path because you have not permission to run cron.
Please check it.

Comment: No, cron.php doesn't check you are logged in; in fact, in most cases it runs from tools that run in automatic.

Comment: Yes, and I am also the logged in with the only account with administrative rights in the site so it should not be the cause of the problem